# Conditional Value at Risk using GARCH models

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch, expected-shortfall

In this paper:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjSlIHYnMj1AhWqNOwKHZfHDhkQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2076-3387%2F9%2F2%2F40%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw12ONJTGtEwL7xIYfPqbhBh
they use the following equation for the Conditional Value at Risk using GARCH:
$$
ES_q(X_{t})=\mu_{t}+\sigma_{t}ES_q(Z)
$$
where $\mu$ is derived from the average prediction models and $\sigma$ is estimated from the volatility prediction models. $ES_q^t(Z)$ is the Conditional Value at Risk of the standardized residuals. I don't understand how to calculate that. Suppose that:

- $r_t$ are the logarithmic returns $r_t = \ln S_{t+1} - \ln S_t$;
- $\varepsilon_t = r_t - \bar{r}$ are the residuals, where $\bar{r}$ is the average return;
- $\sigma_0^2 = \frac{\omega}{1-\alpha -\beta}$ and $\sigma_t^2 = \omega+\alpha \varepsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta \sigma_{t-1}^2$ is the conditional variance at time zero and at time $t$ respectively;
- $\sqrt{\varepsilon_t^2}$ is the realized volatility and $\sqrt{\sigma_t^2}$ is the "fitted" volatility;

Then I don't understand if:

1. $ES_q(Z) = ES_q(\sqrt{\varepsilon^2}-\sqrt{\sigma^2})$ or $ES_q(Z) = ES_q(\varepsilon)$ or $ES_q(Z) = ES_q(r)$?
2. $ES_q(Z)$ is calculated for the entire time series or only for a sliding window?
3. $\mu_t=\bar{r}$ or $\mu_t=$ average loss of the time series?

How can I calculate Conditional Value at Risk using a GARCH model given my conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to question 1:

As mentioned in the linked paper, you estimate the Expected shortfall (ES) or the Value-at-risk (VaR) on the standardized residuals $z_t$, which could be calculated on the basis of a distributional assumption eg. a Gaussian distribution or Student's t-distribution. Remember that the return-process is on the form:

$$r_t \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1} = \mu_t + \sigma_t \cdot z_t, \quad z_t \overset{iid}{\sim} D(0,1),$$
where $z_t$ are the standardized residuals. With regards to the paper, this implies that you estimate expected shortfall as:

$$
\text{ES}^{\alpha}_t\left(\frac{r_t  - \mu}{\sigma_t} \bigg\vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}\right) = \text{ES}_{t\vert t-1}^\alpha\left(z_t\right),
$$
where you have an estimate for $\sigma_t$ via your GARCH model and $\mu = \bar{r}$ is your estimated average returns.

**As an alternative source of information**, you can follow **[Kevin Sheppards' Econometrics Notes](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/files/teaching/mfe/notes/financial-econometrics-2020-2021.pdf)** where he has an entire chapter dedicated to Value-at-risk and Expected shortfall including parametric-methods involving GARCH-dynamics *(see Chapter 8)*.

#### Answer to question 2:

You can estimate expected shortfall on the entire sample-set, as you can with a GARCH model. However, we are often interested in the out-of-sample performance for our specified risk-measures. In that case, you forecast Expected shortfall (or VaR) by doing a 1-step ahead forecast of your GARCH model and back out the estimate for the Expected shortfall. Here, you *can* rely on a sliding window on the GARCH model to get your next conditional volatility estimate.

In the end, it will also be a good idea to evaluate the performance of your estimates for ES and VaR. You can find a sub-chapter about in the Econometric notes linked above *(see chapter 8.5)*. Another reasonable good paper on VaR forecasting and comparison can be found **[here](https://academic.oup.com/jfec/article/8/1/29/862829?casa_token=5MBT-UmeW2gAAAAA:JwTENH5TJFkdFeOMF7i-xcEORZ6p93II30JJVcUNyfl9Wrp1R0tz_Sodd2siLG8IOT_NNY2NA4uA)** if you need some more inspiration.

#### Answer to question 3:

The sentence, "*$\mu$ is defined from the average prediction models*" used by the authors in the [aforementioned paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3387/9/2/40), **is misleading** and I believe their intention was to infer that $\mu_t$ *can* follow a user-specified mean-model. This could be something a lá the Autoregressive model or simply the average returns $\bar{r}$ as you have described above *(be aware that the loss series is just the negation of $r_t$, ie. multiplied by -1)*.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very clear and detailed. I appreciated so much your readings suggestions, in particular the one by Kevin Sheppard. May I ask if  by chance do you have any recommended reading about DCC GARCH and ES/VaR? Or even about plain DCC GARCH?

Comment: The DCC GARCH is very well described in the original paper of [Engle (2002)](https://bit.ly/347OzkM), so that is a good starting point. If you want to model risk-spillover effects (ie. systemic risk)  using DCC-GARCH model you should check out this [paper on CoVaR using DCC GARCH model](https://bit.ly/3qTDQTG) *(CoVaR is the change in VaR of a market/financial system conditioned on a company $i$ being in distress)*. Furthermore, they also implement some backtests for CoVaR.  As for VaR wrt. DCC GARCH model, you can check this [post](https://bit.ly/3nQWwl2) out. it might be of some help.

Comment: There might also be some good discussions in the book, [Quantitative Risk Management](https://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Risk-Management-Techniques-Princeton/dp/0691166277) regarding parametric VaR and ES methods. If you have it available at your local library, you can give it a quick look.